# Create attachment in Jira Cloud via API

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, jira, jira-rest-api

Im trying to create a attachment in Jira Cloud via API using Typescript and Cypress. My domain is https://example.atlassian.net/jira/ but im getting errors all the time

The code is:

```
   const endpoint = `/rest/api/2/issue/${jiraIssue.key}/attachments`;

    const FormData = require('form-data');

    cy.fixture('../../'+filePath, 'binary').then((fileBin) => {

      const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(fileBin);

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('file', blob, { filename: 'issue.feature' });

      for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 

        console.log(key, value);

      }

      cy.request({

        method: 'POST',

        url: `${this.apiUrl}${endpoint}`, // baseUrl is prepend to URL

        body: formData,

        headers: {

          Authorization: `Basic ${this.apiKey}`,

          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',

          'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',

        }

      }).then(response => {

         if (response.status === 204) {
          console.log(`Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
        }


      });
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?